# codeigniter with flexgrid

Tags: codeigniter, flexigrid

I have used href link in the flexigrid rows. on Click it takes me to another page. But on click of the row its making the href link to disappear and its visible only after unselecting row.

Is there any option to stop selecting the row in flexigrid or how to make the link test visible even on selecting the rows.

Please need ur help immd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this condition in flexigrid.js file 
**if(!p.disableSelect)** on line 728 ie. inside $(this).click{
and 
add this line in flexigrid_helper.php inside the build_grid_js
**$grid_js .= "disableSelect : 'true' ,";**

thats it. Its working!